# Search filter is not working in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

this is 1st component as index.jsx

this is array which contains all the data.

```
    let details=[{
    id:'1',
    website: 'amazon',
    username:'harry',
    password: '1234'
   },
 {
  id:'2',
website: 'flipkart',
username:'nowag',
password: 'gfjh'
},
 {
  id:'3',
website: 'skype',
username:'king',
password: 'yesyes'

 },
 {
  id:'4',
website: 'facebook',
username:'deep',
password: 'hellohello'

  }];
```

class app starts here

```
 class  App extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        filter: null
    };
}

setFilter(filter) {
    this.setState({filter: filter})
   }

      render(){
```

error is out here that "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"

```
      let filteredPassword = this.props.details.filter(
          (detail) =>{
              return detail.website.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search)!= -1;
          }
      );

       return (

      <ul>
          <Filter onUpdateFilter={this.setFilter} />
          {
              filteredPassword.map((detail)=>{
               return <Detail item={detail} key={detail.id} />
          })}

      </ul>

         )
       }
     }



      export default App;
```

now there is another component filter.jsx

```
   class Filter extends React.Component{

   constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state= {
        search:'Search'
    };
   }



    updateSearch(event) {
       this.setState({search: event.target.value.substr(0,40)});
       //this.props.onUpdateFilter(event.target.value.substr(0,40))
     }

    render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.search} onchange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

this is way, which i tried to run my filter, but it is not working

Comment: The first thing I see is that state should always be managed from the parent component. Child components should be dumb and not have a state

Comment: i am not getting you, where you are mentioning in the code, can you please tell me briefly.

Comment: You have 2 components, app and filter. Filter is a child of App, therefore filter should not have it's own state. App should contain the state for itself as well as all of it's children and pass the state down to the children as props. State should not be updated/mutated in children and should only be done in the parent.

Comment: ahhh okay... thanks for making my concept clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code should look like :

```
class  App extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        filter: null
    };
    this.setFilter = this.setFilter.bind(this);
}

setFilter(filter) {
    this.setState({filter: filter})
   }

      render(){
      let filteredPassword = this.props.details.filter(
          (detail) =>{
              return detail.website.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search)!= -1;
          }
      );

       return (

      <ul>
          <Filter onUpdateFilter={this.setFilter} />
          {
              filteredPassword.map((detail)=>{
               return <Detail item={detail} key={detail.id} />
          })}

      </ul>

         )
       }
     }



      export default App;


class Filter extends React.Component{

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   }

    updateSearch(event) {
       this.props.onUpdateFilter(event.target.value.substr(0,40))
     }

    render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" defaultValue="Search" onchange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: it gives me still same error       Index.jsx?5537:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the updateSearch function and see what `event.target.value.substr(0,40)` and another breakpoint in setFilter and see what `filter` contains, what do you get?

Comment: can you tell me how to put breakpoint .. i am new to react.js

Comment: It's nothing specific to react. It's just like any other javascript function. You can either put a breakpoint in the chrome console or if you put `debugger;` in your code, it will break there

Comment: do you have teamviewer... can you come through it to help me man ... :)

Comment: just downloaded it. what do i need to do?

Comment: Give me your email address.   i will give you my username and password, so that you can access my pc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117833/discussion-between-erichardson30-and-komal-deep-singh-chahal).

Comment: I have a little bit

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass `details` to the component, you need replace `this.props.details` to `details`

---

And replace this, because `setFilter` has wrong context

```
<Filter onUpdateFilter={this.setFilter} />
```

to this:

```
<Filter onUpdateFilter={filter => this.setFilter(filter)} />
```

or bind in constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        filter: null
    };

    this.setFilter = this.setFilter.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: it works... i passed details to the component. as I wrote above. https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49731/

Comment: you there, i need your help?

Comment: @komaldeepsinghchahal Hello. You can write me an email kenitive@gmail.com

Comment: okay thanks man... now my problem is solved.. next time i will email you. thanks bro